# Error in Fetching API data in flutter. No data fetch

Tags: flutter, http, widget

I am creating a app where I need to fetch category data from API and show it in my Flutter app.

This is my Category Slider code where each slider block show each category:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart';
import 'package:flutter/src/widgets/placeholder.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import '../models/Category.dart';

class CategorySlider extends StatefulWidget {
  const CategorySlider({super.key});

  @override
  State<CategorySlider> createState() => _CategorySliderState();
}

class _CategorySliderState extends State<CategorySlider> {
  List<Category> categories = [];


  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<List<Category>> fetchCategory() async {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/category'));
    var data = jsonDecode(response.body.toString());

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      List<Category> tempCategories = [];
      for (Map<String, dynamic> index in data) {
        tempCategories.add(Category.fromJson(index));
      }
      setState(() {
        categories = tempCategories; // Update the state variable using setState.
      });
      return categories;
    } else {
      return categories;
    }
  }  
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: fetchCategory(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          // print(snapshot.hasData);
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                right: 8,
              ),
              itemCount: categories.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                
                return Container(
                  child: Center(
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                          child: Container(
                            width: 200,
                            height: 120,

                            // width: double.infinity,
                            child: ElevatedButton(
                              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                      side: BorderSide(
                                          color: Color(0xFF1818B4)))),
                              onPressed: () {},
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Text(
                                    '${categories[index].category_name}'
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          } else {
            // print(categories);
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
             
            );
          }
        });
  }

  
}
```

and this is my model `Category.dart`

```
import 'dart:convert';

Category categoryFromJson(String str) => Category.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String categoryToJson(Category data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Category {
    List<Datum> data;

    Category({
        required this.data,
    });

    factory Category.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Category(
        data: List<Datum>.from(json["data"].map((x) => Datum.fromJson(x))),
    );

  get category_name => null;

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "data": List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class Datum {
    int id;
    String image;
    String categoryName;
    String categoryDes;
    int activation;
    DateTime createdAt;
    DateTime updatedAt;

    Datum({
        required this.id,
        required this.image,
        required this.categoryName,
        required this.categoryDes,
        required this.activation,
        required this.createdAt,
        required this.updatedAt,
    });

    factory Datum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Datum(
        id: json["id"],
        image: json["image"],
        categoryName: json["category_name"],
        categoryDes: json["category_des"],
        activation: json["activation"],
        createdAt: DateTime.parse(json["created_at"]),
        updatedAt: DateTime.parse(json["updated_at"]),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "image": image,
        "category_name": categoryName,
        "category_des": categoryDes,
        "activation": activation,
        "created_at": createdAt.toIso8601String(),
        "updated_at": updatedAt.toIso8601String(),
    };
}
```

In this code snippet, the loading indicator just running not fetching data. How to solve this thing?

I think this is an issue with model to fetch data

Comment: Hey have you check that data is there when you fetch.Have you put debugprint for console the data ?

Comment: If you get the data while api call then check console there will be overflow or has size error because you have used axis.horizontal with wrapping to specific height .

Answer (score 0):

Add a categorySliderState Class inside

```
@override
void initState(){
fetchCategory();
}
```

Comment: nothing happened

Comment: Please check and understand the whole code properly then answer so basically he used future builder for fetch the data so no need to add in initstate()